# Watch Simulator Not Loading

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, watchkit, wcsession

Currently trying to create an app that sends data/a message from an Apple Watch to a linked iPhone using WCSession. Code compiles with no errors, but only opens the iOS simulator and says that the WCSession isn't paired. I am therefore not able to test the program.

I tried opening the watchOS simulator and trying another simulator, but it hasn't worked. Here is the code in case that is the issue.

## WATCH APP

```
import SwiftUI
import WatchConnectivity

class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, WCSessionDelegate {
    @Published var message: String = ""
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupWatchConnectivity()
    }
    
    func setupWatchConnectivity() {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }
    
    func sendMessageToPhone() {
        if WCSession.default.isReachable {
            let message = ["text": "Hello, iPhone!"]
            WCSession.default.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        // Handle activation completion
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any]) {
        if let text = message["text"] as? String {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.message = text
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Message from iPhone:")
            Text(viewModel.message)
                .font(.title)
            
            Button(action: viewModel.sendMessageToPhone) {
                Text("Send Message to iPhone")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.setupWatchConnectivity()
        }
    }
}
```

## iOS APP

```
import SwiftUI
import WatchConnectivity

class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, WCSessionDelegate {
    @Published var message: String = ""
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupWatchConnectivity()
    }
    
    func setupWatchConnectivity() {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        // Handle activation completion
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any]) {
        if let text = message["text"] as? String {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.message = text
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Message from Apple Watch:")
            Text(viewModel.message)
                .font(.title)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.setupWatchConnectivity()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure the iPhone you pick has a watch paired. You can add a new simulator to make sure

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. clicked the simulator icon at the top, created a new sim, and paired an Apple Watch.